# Unexpected behaviour of Thread local storage from boost

Tags: c++, boost

I use thread local storage from boost.

In `SolutionA` (dll) in `tls.h` I have:

```
extern __declspec(dllexport) boost::thread_specific_ptr<int> ThreadLocalStorage;
```

In the same solution but in `tls.cpp` with:

```
__declspec(dllexport) boost::thread_specific_ptr<int> ThreadLocalStorage;
```

In `SolutionB` (dll) in `file.pp` I have:

```
__declspec(dllimport) boost::thread_specific_ptr<int> ThreadLocalStorage;
```

and it all compiles with problems.

---

But at runtime I try to change value of `ThreadLocalStorage` in `SolutionB` and `reset` function I have assertion:

```
_Block_Type_Is_Valid (pHead->nBlockUse) Error
```

Right now I can work around this by calling `release` before `reset` but right now when I return from this function to `SolutionA` and try to get `ThreadLocalStorage` I see some random value.

It seems that I have 2 different instances of `ThreadLocalStorage`, how can I fix this ?

**@Edit: It's problem of multiple instances of TLS, and not exported/imported tls from dll.**

I try to summing up all things:

I try to export thread local storage (dllexport)
from firstmodule and import in secondmodule (dllimport) but with no effect. In firstmodule I have Includes/ThreadLocalStorage.h with delaration:

```
#include <boost/thread/tss.hpp>

namespace threads {

                           extern __declspec(dllexport) boost::thread_specific_ptr<int> TlsStorage;
                           extern __declspec(dllexport) int tls_value_storage = 0;

}
```

integer tls_value_storage  is for testing purpose only. There is also Src/ThreadLocalStorage.cpp with:

```
#include <Include/ThreadLocalStorage.h>


namespace threads {

                           __declspec(dllexport) boost::thread_specific_ptr<int> TlsStorage;
                           extern __declspec(dllexport) int tls_value_storage;
}
```

and the last one: in stdafx.h in secondmodule module:

```
namespace threads {

                           extern __declspec(dllimport) boost::thread_specific_ptr<int> TlsStorage;
                           extern __declspec(dllimport) int tls_value_storage2;
}
```

But after all when I try to change set tls in secondmodule

```
            threads::TlsStorage.reset(&new_language_value);
            int *sanity_check = threads::TlxStorage.get();  //.get() return proper value


            Funtion();
```

Now we go to the firstmodule, function() (using the same thread)

```
            int sanity_check_1 = threads::tls_value_storage; //Proper value
            int *sanity_check_2 = threads::TlsStorage.get(); // Something bad happens, return uninitialized tls
```

I think it can be fault of missing extern before __declspec(dllexport) boost::thread_specific_ptr TlsStorage
in ThreadLoalStorage.cpp but when I add "extern" I have:

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) class boost::thread_specific_ptr<int> threads::TlsStorage" (__imp_?TlsStorage@threads@tlx@@3V?$thread_specific_ptr@H@boost@@A)
```

in compiling process. Maybe it's some issue with mangling ?

Comment: I'm not the expert on thread storage, but to me this looks like you really **have** 2 instances: one is implemented in `tls.cpp` the other in `file.pp`. What happens if you make the one in file.pp extern? e.g. `extern __declspec(dllimport) boost::thread_specific_ptr<int> ThreadLocalStorage;` (this could also be done by including `tls.h` in `file.pp`)

Comment: Now I have a problem with export tls, I edit my first post and add some more details.

Comment: Can you add a little bit of formatting, it is pretty difficult to read "through" the automatic formatting...

Comment: Here you go, there is a little better formatting :)